# Update column and Unique Key violation

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I need to clean up a column. The numbers in the column should be like this: `'123 4567'`. But many numbers have an underscore like this: `123_4567`, that I need to get rid of.  I can do that with the Update code below.

The only problem is when some columns already exist with and without underscore. Then I get a Unique Key violation and the "code"  is terminated. I know about `IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON` but it will not work on my Update statement. I also did a `TRY/Catch` without success.

To get the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON` to work seems like the best alternative for me. Then it will not terminate the code when a duplicate key is found and I can alter the script to maybe add `:2` to the rest of the rows that were ignored.

```
UPDATE Table  
    SET [Name] = REPLACE([Name], '_', ' ')  
    WHERE Substring([Name],4,1)='_'
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If it's supported on your version, you might consider writing a [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx) statement - so you can control exactly how the two current rows can be collapsed into one. You would then delete the `_` containing rows.

Answer (score 0):

It's a one time job, right? I would do it like this, adding ":2" directly where the unique key would be violated.

```
UPDATE T SET 
    T.[Name] = 
        REPLACE(T.[Name], '_', ' ')  +
        CASE WHEN T2.NAME IS NOT NULL THEN ':2' ELSE '' END
FROM 
    Table T
LEFT JOIN 
    Table T2 ON T2.[Name] = REPLACE(T.[Name], '_', ' ')  
WHERE 
    Substring(T.[Name],4,1)='_'
```